# Using Index and Match but changing the column when I drag down instead of the row

Tags: arrays, excel, match, offset

I am using this formula to pull the first non 0 value in a column:

```
{=INDEX(FT!D$16:D$610,MATCH(TRUE,FT!D$16:D$610 >0,0))}
```

I want to be able to drag down this formula and shift the column. For example, when I drag down, the next formula would be:

```
{=INDEX(FT!E$16:E$610,MATCH(TRUE,FT!E$16:E$610 >0,0))}
```

and then:

```
{=INDEX(FT!F$16:F$610,MATCH(TRUE,FT!F$16:F$610 >0,0))}
```

Please note that I had to do control-shift-enter when applying these formulas.
I read somewhere that I may need to use offset but I couldn't get it to work.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more info about what goes in an effective Stack Overflow question.  Would you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38376504/edit) to add what you have tried, and what result you got?  Which cells are your formula in?  When you drag, what formula do you get?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of the data and the result for the first formula. I am bit confused as to what the formula is supposed to return. Once i understand that, I (and others) can probably help you more effectively accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The showed formula does not take the first non 0 value in a column but the first value which is greater than 0. Even text will be greater than 0. And negative values will be excluded.

But if you have the columns `D` up to `H`, then the following will do the same as your formula and is fillable downwards 5 Rows (`D` up to `H`).

```
{=INDEX(FT!$D$16:$H$610,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(FT!$D$16:$H$610,0,ROW(A1))>0,0),ROW(A1))}
```

`Row(A1)` is in the first formula. While filling down it changes to `Row(A2)`, `Row(A3)`, ...  which leads to 1, 2, 3, ..., 5 as the column parameter in `INDEX`.

Comment: Thank you! Let me test your knowledge even more.. How would I pull the corresponding date for that first value if there was a column of all of the dates?

Comment: Let's have the dates in column `C`, then `{=INDEX(FT!$C$16:$C$610,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(FT!$D$16:$H$610,0,ROW(A1))>0,0))}`. Did i pass the test? ;-)

Comment: With flying colors!